# Grab table by ID and iterate over rows one at a time

Tags: javascript, dom, dynamic, iteration

I would like to use

```
var merch = document.getElementById('merch');
```

to retrieve a table on my webpage, which is dynamically populated. Then I would like to iterate over the table, one row at a time, grabbing the

```
<td>
```

elements and storing each of them as a string in an array. Each row will have its own array.

Can someone give me a clue as to how to accomplish this? I feel certain there is a simple method I just haven't found in my searches.

Thank you in advance for your consideration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***[The working demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/9skPF/)***

```
var merch = document.getElementById('merch');

// this will give you a HTMLCollection
var rows = merch.rows;

// this will change the HTMLCollection to an Array
var rows = [].slice.call(merch.rows);   

// if you want the elements in the array be string.
// map the array, get the innerHTML propery.
var rows = [].slice.call(merch.rows).map(function(el) {
    return el.innerHTML;
});
```

[map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: freakin sweet! I knew it had to be simple.

Comment: can you explain what this signifies: "[]." ? I'm trying to learn what this does. It looks like a shorthand version for iterating all items in an array.

Comment: `[].slice` is get the array's slice method, same with `Array.prototype.slice`

Comment: Is "function(el) {return el.innerHTML;}" a generic function? Why use that there?

Comment: It is a anonymous function, used as a callback.

Comment: And merch.rows...what should I google to read about this? It looks like a constant, but returns an HTMLCollection...

Comment: Check here, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/table.rows which could be found easily by google :)

Comment: Ahhhsome. You have given me a lot to learn. Thank you for your quickness and generosity of knowledge. :)

Comment: @xdazz—couple of issues. Don't treat host objects like native objects, it will fail in a good proportion of browsers in use (e.g. passing an HTMLCollection as `this` to a built–in method). Also *map* is an ES5 feature that isn't supported by a good number of browsers in use.

Comment: @RobG:What would you do there if you couldn't use map?

Comment: @RobG I have given the link of `map`. And What do you mean by treat the host objects like native objects in this code? An example will be welcome, thx.

Comment: @nodirtyrockstar If you don't use map, you could just use a normal for loop, and push the element to an array.

Comment: @xdazz—as in the comment, e.g. `[].slice.call(merch.rows)`. Try it in IE8 in quirks mode (and probably standards mode too).

Comment: @RobG Yes, IE...Could you give a explanation whey IE has the error `this is not a Javascript object`, Doesn't host object is object too?

Comment: @RobG-are you using IE 9 to check IE 8? Because I am discovering that IE9's emulation of the older browsers is about as accurate as Dreamweaver.

Comment: @xdazz—the short answer: host objects are explicitly exempted from ECMA–262 so they don't have to behave like native objects. There's much more information in articles like [What’s wrong with extending the DOM](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/) and [don’t modify objects you don’t own](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/03/02/maintainable-javascript-dont-modify-objects-you-down-own/). It makes sense to make DOM objects as ECMAScript compliant as possible, but that wasn't Microsoft's strategy until about IE 9.

Comment: I am actually going to go with merch.rows and then break it down with rows.cells inside a loop. This thread has been enlightening!

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use jQuery for this, it'll make it much easier. Then you can do something like this.

**HTML Table**

```
<table id="iterateOverThisTable">
  <tr>
    <td>One</td>
    <td>Two</td>
    <td>Three</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>One</td>
    <td>Two</td>
    <td>Three</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>One</td>
    <td>Two</td>
    <td>Three</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**JS File (with jQuery already included)**

```
$(function() {
  var rows = [];

  $("#tableToIterateOver tr").each(function() {
    var = cells = [];

    $(this).find('td').each(function() {
      cells.push($(this).text());
    });

    rows.push(cells);
  });
})
```